# Select Left Join Two Tables Where Today is Between Two Datetime Columns in Second Table

Tags: mysql

**EDIT** To simplify this further.

Let's take a look at this structure:

> Table1: idProduct (int) | Name (varchar)
>
> Table2: idDay (int) | idProduct (int) | date_start(datetime) | date_end (datetime)

idProduct is a common column in both tables. Table two contains data similar to this:

```
0, 2, 11/22/2012, 11/22/2012
1, 2, 11/23/2012, 11/23/2012
2, 2, 11/24/2012, 11/24/2012
3, 2, 00/00/0000, 11/25/2012
4, 2, 11/25/2012, 00/00/0000
```

Note that date_start, date_end or both may be all zeroes, in which case this upper or lower limit is considered unbound/unlimited.

In the above case I would like to select idProduct with ID 2 ONLY if today's date is between the period - earliest date in date_start and latest date in date_end.
If date_start is 00/00/0000 always return the product BUT if date_end is in the future. The reverse applies for date_end being all zeroes and date_start being set. If both columns are zeroes return the product.

Comment: date_start and date_end are stored as DATETIME ? or TIMESTAMP ? or ?

Comment: Edited. They are both DATETIME.

Comment: my query will work anyway because i am extracting date from datetime field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the "LEFT JOIN" requirement in your question : just in your title. So

```
SELECT t1.idProduct, t1.Name
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.idProduct = t2.idProduct
WHERE DATE(t2.date_start) < DATE(NOW())--this will also take values with DATETIME = 0000
AND (DATE(t2.date_end) > DATE(NOW()) OR YEAR(t2.date_end) = 0)
GROUP BY t1.idProduct, t1.Name
```

or if you want to check if product has at least one start_date smaller than today (or 0) and at least one end_date bigger than today(or 0), even if start_date and end_date don't share the same idDay :

```
SELECT t1.idProduct, t1.Name
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.idProduct IN
    (SELECT t2.IdProduct
    FROM table t2
    GROUP BY t2.IdProduct
    HAVING 
    MIN(t2.date_start) <= DATE(NOW()) AND 
    (MAX(t2.date_end) >= DATE(NOW()) OR YEAR(MAX(t2.date_end)) = 0))
```

It will take :

min start_date = 0 and max end_date = 0

min start_date = 0 and max end_date >= today

min start_date <= today and max end_date =0

min start_date <= today and max end_date >= today

Comment: Good response. I thank you for which, but this does not work in my case, because date_end and date_start contain the same date for each separate row (each row has different dates though), so the AND operator between the two date checks fails in at least one of the cases (a date can not be both before or after today if the two columns contain the same date). Also, I don't care about the values of the rows of the second table. I just want to return products that for at least one day (maximum date_end in table2) are after today and at least one day (minimum date_start) are before today.

Comment: @user1364793 if it fails when date_start and date_end = 0, then my change in the second query (last line) should do it. You said you would take result if max end_date = 0000 ? Is this true, or not ? If yes, second query should work, now.

Comment: I believe you left out the FROM clause in your second query. Also, consider the edit I made to the question.

Comment: @user1364793 right, Edited. I also changed `<` and `>` to `<=` and `>=` (inclusive between instead of exclusive). See my explanation at end, if it's wrong, I didn't catch your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  t1.idproduct,
  t1.name
from table as t1
  left join table2 as t2
    on t1.idproduct = t2.idproduct
where date(date_start) < date(now())
    and date(date_end) > date(now())
```

EDITED

```
select
  t1.idproduct,
  t2.idproduct,
  t2.name
from table as t1
  left join (select
               max(idproduct),
               name
             from table2
             where date(date_start) < date(now())
                 and date(date_end) > date(now())) as t2
    on t1.idproduct = t2.idproduct
```

And of course it will not select those records where the end date is 00:00:00

Comment: Hmmm, and if date_end is zeroes ?

Comment: This will return multiple rows for the same product where the date is between date_start and date_end, because table 2 contains multiple rows with the same idProduct.